# POST values of disabled form elements

Tags: php, disabled-input

I have a form in which I need to disable an array of checkboxes and a few fields so that the user cannot change/alter their values. When I submit the form though, the POST values of the disabled elements are missing/null. How can I manage what I'm trying to do without this problem?

Right now I'm disabling the fields by disabling the container div like this:

```
#unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor:not-allowed; 

}
```

Comment: Quit tagging your titles please.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, there are 3 solutions I can think of:

- Make them `readonly` by adding the `readonly` property to the element.
- disable them in CSS/JavaScript. Color it like it's disabled, and don't allow editing with JavaScript,
- Leave it disabled, and remove the disabled on submit.

Take your pick :)

Comment: How do I remove the disabled on submit?

Comment: I wrote a small script that loops through all form elements and enables them when form is submitted. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

you could use `readonly` instead of `disabled` wich is almost the same for the user (can't be editet) but the values of `readonly`-elements get submitted while the `disabled` ones don't.

note that there are [some other differences](http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/) between readonly and disabled wich might lead to other problems for you:

> **The Disabled attribute**
>
> - Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar to
>     form check boxes that are not checked.)
> - Some browsers may override or provide default styling for disabled form elements. (Gray out or emboss text) Internet Explorer 5.5 is
>     particularly nasty about this.
> - Disabled form elements do not receive focus.
> - Disabled form elements are skipped in tabbing navigation.
>
> **The Read Only Attribute**
>
> - Not all form elements have a readonly attribute. Most notable, the  ,  , and  elements do not have readonly
>     attributes (although thy both have disabled attributes)
> - Browsers provide no default overridden visual feedback that the form element is read only. (This can be a problem… see below.)
> - Form elements with the readonly attribute set will get passed to the form processor.
> - Read only form elements can receive the focus
> - Read only form elements are included in tabbed navigation.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much point in sending the same data to and fro.

Just leave in on the **server side** and then use it upon submit.

Besides, assuming that

> user cannot change/alter their values.

is quite silly.

Comment: Its a form in which I need to have some predefined selections according to the user type which differ from group to group, therefore the fields must be visible but not enabled.

Comment: I am not talking of the visibility on the client side. I am talking of the server side, which already has these values - sdo, there is absolutely no point in sending them again. And about silly assumption that user cannot alter the values

Comment: I came here looking for a solution to send disabled data to the server, when in fact I don't need to do it at all, much simpler solution. thanks

Comment: i had the problem that a part of a form should be generated by javascript with a value that the user selects before outside the form. after the user clicked the button "add to form" the selected value should not be changed again after adding it to form but must be submitted because the serverside have to know this generated fieldname and value. therefore readonly is the perfect way!

Answer (score 0):

You could use "read-only" instead of disabled, which should have the wanted effect

You can also use javascript to submit your form, and pre-submit un-disable (enable :P ) the various fields?